# How to install libvips on Alpine 3.8?

Tags: linux, alpine-linux, vips, alpine-package-keeper

I try to install vips-dev package to alpine linux 3.8. But get following error:

```
docker run -it --rm alpine:3.8 /bin/sh -c "apk add --update --no-cache --repository http://dl-3.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing vips-dev"

fetch http://dl-3.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  pc:fftw3 (missing):
    required by: vips-dev-8.7.4-r1[pc:fftw3] vips-dev-8.7.4-r1[pc:fftw3] vips-dev-8.7.4-r1[pc:fftw3]
```

How to solve it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is a known packaging issue of `vips-dev` on `edge/testing`:
https://bugs.alpinelinux.org/issues/9561

As a workaround, make sure to add both `edge/main` and `edge/testing` repositories to your apk command:

```
sudo docker run -it --rm alpine:3.8 /bin/sh -c "apk add --update --no-cache --repository http://dl-3.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing --repository http://dl-3.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main vips-dev"
```

**Update, 30/5/19:**

[`vips-dev`](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/community/x86_64/vips-dev) has moved from  the `edge/testing` branch to `edge/community`, and updated to version 8.8.0-r0. Therefore, the updated command line is:

```
sudo docker run -it --rm alpine:3.8 /bin/sh -c "apk add --update --no-cache --repository http://dl-3.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community --repository http://dl-3.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main vips-dev"
```

Comment: This solution was working for me, but today I'm now getting `ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints: vips-dev (missing)` from every alpine repository I've tried (dl-1, dl-2, dl-3, dl-4, dl-cdn...) . Visiting the repo url in a browser shows a 404...

Comment: @AaronHill `vips-dev` has moved from the `testing` branch to the `community` branch, so simply change `testing` to `community` above. Here's the new package link: https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/community/x86_64/vips-dev

Comment: thank you!  Might I ask how you knew this?  I'm not sure how I would have figured this out on my own...

Comment: @AaronHill using Alpine's package search - it's the best!
https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages
Just searched for `vips-dev`. Note you can also search a regex (for example, `vips*`), and also search for contents.